# update in mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

Is there any way to run UPDATE or INSERT inside a SELECT statement in mysql?

Comment: a little more details / a use case could help.

Comment: Would you like an UPDATE with SELECT? e.g. `UPDATE tbl JOIN (SELECT...) AS der SET tbl.field1 = der.field2`

Comment: What's your actual need?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
INSERT california_authors (au_id, au_lname, au_fname)
SELECT au_id, au_lname, au_fname
FROM authors
WHERE State = 'CA'
```

More on that matter: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records

Comment: NO, this is a SELECT command in an INSERT command. I need a INSERT/UPDATE/equivalent inside an SELECT command.

Comment: You select something and then you try to insert/update something, based on the select, because otherwise you could just select or just insert/update. Maybe i'm wrong, but from the 'task' perspective the above might fulfill what you try to do (even though not formally ..).